# Enum usage to restrict class attribute values

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, enum

I am using enums in python3 for the first time but unsure if I am using them correctly.

I want to restrict the 'allowed values' for a class attribute `ArticleMetadata.article_type` to those defined within an `ArticleTypes` Enum class.

**Here's my code:**

```
from enum import Enum

class ArticleMetadata(object):

    ArticleTypes = Enum('ArticleTypes', 'original modified', module=__name__)

    def is_in_enum(self, value, Enum):
        """Verify that a value is contained within a defined Enum object.

        Raises:
            ValueError: If the value is not contained within the defined Enum.
        """
        if value in Enum.__members__:
            return True
        else:
            raise ValueError("Value {0} not in Enum list.".format(value))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Set class attributes."""

        self.article_type = (kwargs['article_type'] if 'article_type' in kwargs.keys()
                              and self.is_in_enum(kwargs['article_type'], self.ArticleTypes)
                              else None
                              )
```

**Usage**

```
> foo = ArticleMetadata(article_type='original')
> foo.article_type
'original'
> bar = ArticleMetadata(article_type='invalid')
*** ValueError: Value invalid not in Enum list.
```

This code works, but having to write an `is_in_enum` method seems clunky, and I would have thought that this functionality would be natively part of enums somehow??

Also, no errors are raised if I later run `foo.article_type = 'invalid'`, which doesn't seem right!

Am I missing a common usage pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I think for it to be completely safe (even against re-assigning later), you should make `AtricleMetadata.article_type` a `property`:

```
from enum import Enum

class ArticleMetadata(object):

    ArticleTypes = Enum('ArticleTypes', 'original modified', module=__name__)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Set class attributes."""
        self.article_type = kwargs.get('article_type', None)

    @property
    def article_type(self):
        return self._article_type

    @article_type.setter
    def article_type(self, value):
        if value in self.ArticleTypes.__members__:
            self._article_type = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Value {} not in ArticleType list.".format(value))
```

In this case you don't need your helper function any more (at the price of losing this general function and having to write a getter and setter for every property for which you want this kind of protection). Note that I used `dict.get` to make your initialization easier.

Also note that this can still be tricked, because Python has no real private members. So you can still do this:

```
>>> a = ArticleMetadata(article_type="original")
>>> a._article_type = "invalid"
>>> a.article_type
'invalid'
```

Comment: Overall this is the better answer as it responds to the entire question.  Regarding the direct access to the `_article` attribute: while it cannot be prevented, some code could be added to the getter to check `self._article_type` and raise an error if it is not valid.  Not perfect, but would help catch the problem sooner.

Comment: It seems you could still make this more general by using a [descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149431/943773) that takes the attribute's associated Enum as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

- You get no benefit for raising an error in `is_in_enum`. It's actually a hindrance.
  I'd expect to use that function as followed:

  ```
  if foo.is_in_enum(key):
      # do something
  else:
      # do something
  ```

  However, to correctly use your function I'd have to use:

  ```
  try:
      foo.is_in_enum(key)
  except ValueError:
      # do something
  else:
      # do something
  ```

  Instead just change it to return your if statement.
- You can use `**kwargs` with keyword arguments. Use that instead.

And so I'd use:

```
from enum import Enum


class ArticleMetadata(object):
    ArticleTypes = Enum('ArticleTypes', 'original modified', module=__name__)

    def in_enum(self, value, Enum):
        """Verify that a value is contained within a defined Enum object."""
        return value in Enum.__members__

    def __init__(self, article_type=None, **kwargs):
        """Set class attributes."""
        if article_type is None or not self.in_enum(article_type, self.ArticleTypes):
            raise ValueError("Value {} not in Enum list.".format(article_type))
        self.article_type = article_type
```

Answer (score 2):

In any event, I would avoid the inline logic at the initialization of your attributes and abstract that out to a validator funtion. There are several approaches to class attribute validations you can follow, some of which are mentioned here in other answers. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/6-approaches-to-validate-class-attributes-in-python-b51cffb8c4ea) describes several fairly well.

Following the example presented by @Graipher's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/162517/251680), here is a general approach that solves the problems you mentioned (namely handling the case in which an incorrect attribute is set after init), along with avoiding the declarations of multiple getter/setter descriptors for each attribute.

Here I also am passing the Enum member's as the parameter values, so as to make it a bit easier for a user to navigate available options. It is best to validate at input, and in the case of setting an attribute after init, I feel the best way to do this is by forcing the use of the Enum to eliminate erroneous possibilites.

```py
from enum import Enum, IntEnum
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any


class EnumAttribute:
    """General descriptor for validated Enum attributes"""

    __slots__ = ("_attr", "_Enum")

    def __init__(self, attr: str, enum: Enum):
        self._attr = attr
        self._Enum = enum

    def __get__(self, obj: object, objtype: type):
        return obj.__dict__[self._attr]

    def __set__(self, obj: object, enum_member: Any):
        enum_members = self._Enum.__members__.values()
        if enum_member not in enum_members:
            value_strings = [
                f"{str(v)} ({v.value})" for v in enum_members
            ]
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid value '{str(enum_member)}' for attribute `{self._attr}` "
                f"must be one of: {', '.join(value_strings)}"
            )
        obj.__dict__[self._attr] = enum_member.value


class Strings(Enum):
    A = "first option"
    B = "second option"


class Integers(IntEnum):
    A = 10
    B = 20

class Datetimes(Enum):
    A = datetime(2021,1,1)
    B = datetime(2021,2,2)


class Example:
    """Example class using the validating descriptor"""

    str_attr = EnumAttribute("str_attr", Strings)
    int_attr = EnumAttribute("int_attr", Integers)
    datetime_attr = EnumAttribute("datetime_attr", Datetimes)

    def __init__(self, str_attr: Strings, int_attr: Integers, datetime_attr: Floats):
        self.str_attr = str_attr
        self.int_attr = int_attr
        self.datetime_attr = datetime_attr
```

Usage:

```py
>>> example = Example(Strings.A, Integers.B, Datetimes.A)
>>> example.str_attr
'first option'

>>> example.datetime_attr
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0)

>>> example = Example(Strings.A, Integers.B, "C")
ValueError: Invalid value 'C' for attribute `datetime_attr` must be one of: Datetimes.A (2021-01-01 00:00:00), Datetimes.B (2021-02-02 00:00:00)

>>> example = Example(Strings.A, Integers.B, Datetimes.C)
AttributeError: C
```